# Problem importing torch in command prompt, but it works directly in VS code / Jupyter

Tags: flask, anaconda, pytorch, command-prompt

I am trying to run a flask app in my command prompt on Windows 10. Whenever I try to run it, it errors out when trying to import torch. I have created a fresh environment and installed the latest pytorch from this page https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ but it still doesn't work in command prompt. Oddly, if I just execute code that says "import torch" in jupyter notebook or VS code, it doesn't error out. It only gives me the error in Command Prompt.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: I suspect your command prompt might be pointing to another Python installation different from Anaconda. What is your output for `where python`? As a quick workaround to use Anaconda in the cmd, open the Start Menu and type Anaconda Prompt. In my installation, `where python` shows two paths in the Anaconda Prompt, one for Conda (first) and a second for the system's Python. Regular command prompt only shows system's Python.

Comment: So my Anaconda prompt does show both paths, but so does my command prompt (just in a different order if that makes any difference). Does that seem like it would cause an issue?

Comment: If system Python is placed first in your `PATH`, it will be the one called instead of Anaconda's. If you change the order in your `PATH` variable, command prompt will call the one that comes first. Try printing `echo %PATH%` in both terminals to see the difference. The simplest solution would be to just use Anaconda Prompt instead, since it already fixes the `PATH` (if there is no reason for using it). Plus, using Anaconda Prompt is advised [to avoid interfering with other software](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#id5).

Comment: A quick workaround to check if this is the solution would be to `set PATH=C:\Anaconda3\;%PATH%`, assuming it's installed in `C:\Anaconda3\`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** If possible, use Anaconda Prompt. It's accessible from the Start Menu > Anaconda > Anaconda Prompt.

**Long answer:** The problem is due to the order of the different Python installations in the `PATH` variable, as you can see with `echo %PATH%`. System Python comes first, which can be seen with `which python`.

The recommendation is to use Anaconda Prompt, since it properly sets up the `PATH` variable with all required Anaconda paths. More importantly, it avoids interfering with [other software in regular command prompt](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#id5). So, your command prompt won't have any unintended consequences from using Anaconda.

If there is a reason that requires you to use regular command prompt, you can change the order with `set PATH=C:\Anaconda\;%PATH%` (temporary for this command prompt) or `setx PATH=C:\Anaconda\;%PATH%` ([permanent](https://superuser.com/a/916652/201187)). There are other libs that may be required to be included as well, which you can check by printing the `PATH` variable at the Anaconda Prompt.

Another option (Win10): Start Menu > type 'environment' > click 'Edit the system environment variables'. Click Advanced > Environment Variables... Double click `Path` and change the order between system Python and Anaconda Python.